# Ajax Alternate?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

I have a gridview & need to update a row data without refreshing the page.I tried using ajax updatepanel / Script manager.. but i dont want to use Ajax for this task atall. can anyone please suggest what are other options i can use here ?

Answer (score 1):

Forget asp.ajax. Use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) instead.

Here is an example you could try: [Some ASP.NET GridView UI Tips and Tricks using jQuery](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=259&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)

**EDIT**
Um... reading you Q again. Did you mean not using Javascript, or just ASP Ajax specifically?

Comment: Thanks for the link Steve, just wondering in case javascript is not enabled on the clients browser then what else i can do ?

Comment: If JavaScript is not available you cannot change the page without refreshing. That is the nature of HTML and JavaScript.  Refreshing only when there is no Javascript is quite possible, however.